# Can I use a drop statement to delete specific principals from database after completing a restore from Production in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

I have task to automate the process of taking a copy of a specific production environment and using the `.bak` file to restore a different environment (TEST or DEV) so that they don't end up out of sync. I understand this isn't exactly best practice, but it's the best solution right now for the problem we're addressing.

I obviously don't want to keep the principals/roles/permissions that my Prod environment has in my Test environment, and so I am looking for a way to delete the principals and then put the original test ones back.

I found Kenneth Fisher's example [here.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83481/how-to-save-and-then-restore-permissions-after-refreshing-a-database) However, I'm wondering if that solution is a little over engineered for my purposes.

Is there a reason I shouldn't just use a script like below to delete exactly which principals I need to from the restored test file and then use Mr. Fisher's script to put the old principals back?

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @name sysname

DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR 
    SELECT name 
    FROM sys.database_principals 
    WHERE [type] in (N'U',N'S',N'G') 
      AND name NOT IN ('dbo', 'guest', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA', 'sys', 'public', 'codaprod_user', 'NT SERVICE\HealthService')

OPEN cursor_name

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name INTO @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM sys.schemas WHERE [name] = ''' + @name + ''')
                 BEGIN
                     DROP SCHEMA [' + @name + N']
                 END
                 BEGIN TRY 
                     DROP USER [' + @name + N'] 
                 END TRY 
                 BEGIN CATCH END CATCH;'

    --PRINT 'USE ' + DB_NAME() + ';' + @sql
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name INTO @name
END

CLOSE cursor_name
DEALLOCATE cursor_name;
GO
```

Comment: If the end result is similar and is what you want, why not...

Comment: @GolezTrol My concern is that my deletion doesn't remove everything that would be copied into my test env from the prod .bak.

Comment: I must admit, I'm a little confused by your set up. It sounds like you're saying that your applying changes to Production, and then applying them to test and Dev. Am I misunderstanding? If not, you're working in reverse; you make changes (and script them out) in Dev and applying them upwards; not the other way round.

Comment: @Lamu my interpretation was that he meant they want to keep data in sync, rather than schema. I hope so anyway :p

Comment: @Ben That's exactly it.